# How to call ConversationHandler with an InlineButtonKeyboard?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

This is my handler:

```py
    ads_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('add', ads_start)],

        states={
            ADS_WAY: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, ads_way)],
            ADS_FW: [MessageHandler(filters.ALL, ads_fw)],
            # ADS: [MessageHandler(filters.ALL, ads)],
            # ADS_CONFIRM: [MessageHandler(filters.ALL,ads_confirm)],
            ADS_CONFIRMFW: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, ads_confirmfw)],
        },
        fallbacks=[MessageHandler(filters.Regex('^⬅️ Cancel$'), stop)]
    )


app.add_handler(ads_handler)
```

It's working well when user send /add command, but I want to enter into the conversation from the code.

How to do that?

I tried putting `CallbackQueryHandler` in the `entry_points` but it raised an error.

Comment: If you got an exception, please post the full traceback.

Comment: No, That is `CallbackQuery will not tracked` warning, not error